# How can I control the action of onbeforeunload in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got a problem about `onbeforeunload` recently that I need to pop up a voting page when users try to close  their IE browsers.I did it by using:

```
<body onbeforeunload="makevote()">
```

And the main structure of `makevote()` in javascript is as follows:

```
function makevote()
{
    comet.distruct();
    if(csid != null && isvote == null)
    {
        window.event.returnValue = false
        window.event.returnValue='press “cancel” to vote please！'
        showComDiv(popvote,"popiframe",400,120,'your vote here','dovote()');
    }

}
```

In last three months this voting function performed so ugly that I got only less than 8,000 votes from  more than 4,50,000 vistors.I think the problem is, when the users try to close their browsers,the `onbeforeunload` property pops up a comfirm box which covered my voting box while most users click the OK button,which means close comfirming is done,as a habit.So my question is how can I control the comfirming box made by `onbeforeunload` myself? For example if I click the "OK" ,I'll go to the voting box instead of closing my IE.So far what I can do is only defining the message it shows.And is there any other better way to do this?Help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, you can't.

This is built-in behaviour, designed to only allow very minimal changes for security purposes. It's the same in every browser; FF, Chrome, etc, all will behave the same way.

The primary purpose for the beforeunload is for things like allowing the users the option to save changes before their changes are lost.

Besides, if your users are leaving, it's already too late - they won't want to answer a survey anymore, they're done!

Comment: Sorry :-/. I've wanted to change it before as well, so I know your pain.