# on browser reload/refresh/close alert and then ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to fire an alert on browser close? If user confirm "reload/close" then want to execute some ajax stuff. This is I have tried so far

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'This will close your chat session. Are you Sure!';
    var meta_id = $('#meta_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: site_url + '/chat/send_offline',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: {
            meta_id: meta_id
        }
    });
}
```

As far I know code not execute after the `return` statement. **So is it possible to alert and execute ajax code simultaneously if user confirm??**

Comment: You want to use `confirm()` instead of `return`.

Comment: @Justinas In `onbeforeunload` event `confirm()` or `alert()` doesn't work

Comment: Actually some web apps have “Do you want to close this window”  error at running forms,or doing http calls . I think you can search how can you activate it

Answer (score 0):

I found this in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Do you want to leave this page ?";

  // Call AJAX RIGHT HERE

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko and Trident
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko and WebKit
});
```

You have to call the Ajax before return in the function. Because return break the execution of the function.

Comment: This will not solve the issue because if user close browser and alert message shown after ajax call then all action will be wrong (if user cancel the browser close)

Comment: It seems that is not possible to catch the anwser of the user. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5400059/4547547)

But you can use the unload event to make your Ajax call ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload

Answer (score -1):

Maybe chrome.runtime.onSuspend or chrome.windows.onRemoved will help you?

Comment: What about firefox, IE? How to use that? Link to documentation?