# Capture before closing browser page

Tags: javascript

This is my scenario:
A user start editing a post, upload a photo, but then he closes the browser, or jump to a different page.

I want to be able to delete the photo uploaded and warn the user of the consequnces.

I know there is a function window.onbeforeunload
But I'm not sure if I get it right

```
window.onbeforeunload = askExit;
function askExit(){
        return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";

}
```

Now, how do I capture the button press "leave this page"
So I can fire a second function to clean the session, photos, etc?

Comment: `window.onunload = function(){ console.log("unloaded"); }` when "leave this page" is clicked, page unloads. But be careful, everything (dom, ajax calls etc) will be cleaned up.

Comment: Also see this the answer to this question.  It used jQuery, but the principles are the same.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057224/jquery-prompt-to-save-data-onbeforeunload/11057949#11057949

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512991/how-can-i-control-the-action-of-onbeforeunload-in-ie/2513264#2513264):

> The primary purpose for the beforeunload is for things like allowing the users the option to save changes before their changes are lost.

However, you *could* technically do this with a bit of `onfocus`/`onunload` wizardry:

```
var isFromUnloadDialog = false;

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
  isFromUnloadDialog = true;
  return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
});

window.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (isFromUnloadDialog) {
    // User canceled the unload
    isFromUnloadDialog = false;
  }
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  // User didn't cancel the unload; clean up
});
```

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) also may be worth a read if you haven't taken a look at it already.